# shell script how to compare file name with expected filename but different extention in single line

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have doubt in shell script
I will describe the scenario, $file is containing the file name of my interest,
consider $file can contain foo.1, foo.2, foo.3 here foo will be constant,
but .1,.2,.3 will change, i want to test this in single line in if statement something like

`if [ $file = "foo.[1-9]" ]; then`
`echo "File name is $file"`
`fi'`

i know above script doesn't work :) can anyone suggest what should i refer for this ?

Comment: The `bash` tag is actually incorrect if you are on Busybox, but since you already got a Bash answer, I won't take it out.

Comment: You are right, first i was trying it on bash and then i moved script to busybox shell so this confusion arose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[[` instead for regex matching.

```
if [[ $file =~ ^foo\.[1-9]$ ]] ; ...
```

Comment: exactly the answer what i was looking for but it doesn't work in busybox shell, i know i didn't mention that in question, but just for curiosity i am asking, is there any other solution i can try in busybox shell ?

Comment: This is a Bash extension. Busybox doesn't have Bash. My answer should be portable to any Bourne-compatible shell, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Trim any extension, then see if it's "foo"?

```
base=${file%.[1-9]}
if [ "$base" = "foo" ]; then
    echo Smashing success
fi
```

Equivalently, I always like to recommend `case` because it's portable and versatile.

```
case $file in
    foo.[1-9] ) echo Smashing success ;;
esac
```

The syntax may seem weird at first but it's well worth knowing.

Both of these techniques should be portable to any Bourne-compatible shell, including Dash and POSIX `sh`.

Comment: this can be a solution but, If i want to make strict check for files foo.1 to foo.9 then i cant do that right ? is it possible to do that in single line in `if` ? i know i can extract the extension and do that but i am checking if there is better way to do that.

Comment: case solution is the one i was looking for i think !! :) i saw after i loaded edited answer.

Comment: Edited to only trim a single-digit extension in the first example.

Comment: Though Ignacio's answer is exact answer but i am writing script for busybox shell and it seems regex matching doesnt work there. But case solution worked perfectly fine thank you very much.